# C++ Compile Error, Help Needed - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I am trying to get this to compile, but every time I go to compile main.cpp I get the same error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "tlogic::tlogic()", referenced from:
      _main in ccAcayG4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried debugging it for a while, but the error seems to persist. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "tlogic.h"

int main()
{
        tlogic test;

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

tlogic.h:

```
#ifndef TLOGIC_H
#define TLOGIC_H

class tlogic {
public:
        tlogic();
        tlogic(bool);
        ~tlogic();
        void init();
        void get_command();

private:
        bool debug;
};

#endif
```

And finally, tlogic.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "tlogic.h"

tlogic::tlogic()
{
        cout << "Testing" << endl;
        debug = false;
}

tlogic::tlogic(bool debug_)
{
        cout << "Testing 2" << endl;
        debug = debug_;
}

tlogic::~tlogic()
{
}

void tlogic::game_init()
{
}

void tlogic::get_command()
{
}
```

Thank you for the help.

EDIT: Fixed tlogic::glogic, etc.

Comment: Try something simpler. Does a simple "hello world" compile and link?

Comment: Compiler complains about "glogic::glogic()" but you have no such class now. It seems like main.o was not recompiled after some renaming. Try to clean project and build it from scratch.

Comment: Nope. Even when you take the class away and just declare hello_world() in the header file, it gives the same error. hello_world() is defined in tlogic.cpp, but it looks like the compiler isn't linking the file.

Comment: `tlogic::~glogic()` definitely shouldn't compile.

Comment: The glogic was a mistake... its fixed in my code, sorry. Made edit in post.

Comment: Please post real code, the link line you are using and the complete error that matches the code which you actually show.

Comment: That's the real code now. And that is the complete error that is shows. I am compiling with g++. Doing "g++ -o prog main.cpp"

Comment: So you link a single source file (`main.cpp`), not `tlogic.cpp` as well?

Comment: what is you compilation/linking command?? is it something like: "g++ main.cpp" or "g++ main.cpp tlogic.cpp"? the first will result in this kind of error, you can use the latter, but I recommend to read about compiling and linking if this was your error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
g++ -o prog main.cpp tlogic.cpp
```

When you are compiling and linking in a single step you need to make sure that you pass all of the source files required to make your complete program to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem. Missed the compilation of tlogic.cpp... stupid mistake.